# modalpopupextender resizes the screen?

Tags: ajax, modalpopupextender

Can anyone PLEASE explain to me if this is expected behavior.

I have an asp.net site that looks good and all fits on one page so no scrolling is needed.  I am trying to show additional content by using the modalpopupextender when the user clicks a specific button.  The content shown is inside a panel and not shown on load since the display:none is used.

The problem is that when the user clicks the button, the panel content shows BUT it resizes that portion of the screen to be the full width and height of the screen so other elements inside the table view are now shifted way off of the screen.  It also adds a vertical and horizontal scrollbar that scrolls forever and never stops.

I have done hours of research on this and have tried everything I have found by setting the overflow:hidden etc...  The overflow hidden would work except that all of the other elements on the screen get moved way out into no mans land.

The question is, should the modalpopupextender be affecting the  size when the panel is shown and shifting the other elements off of the screen?  It doesn't do when I run the code on another machine, so I am wondering if it could be a bug in the Ajax toolkit version I am using but I am not sure how to check the version that is installed.

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Just dealt with this; however it was exclusive to IE---FF, Chrome and Opera handled the modal appropriately. I discovered that the DOCTYPE needed to be set to XHTML 1.0 transitional instead of HTML 4 in header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

needs to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I actually tracked it down to a badly commented out script tag in the master page.  I still don't know why it didn't throw a compile error. Thanks for the reply.